# Is trace map well-defined for an endomorphism of free-module over $A[G]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a commutative ring $A$ and a finite group $G$(not commutative), form $A[G]$.

Given matrices $M,A,B\in M_n(A[G])$, with $AB=BA=I_n$. Is it true that $\sum_{i,j,k}a_{ij}m_{jk}b_{ki}=\sum_im_{ii}$ in $A[G]$?

There's another try to give a definition: Write $M=\sum_{g\in G}gM_g$ with $M_g\in M_{n\times n}(A)$, define $Tr(M)=\sum Tr(M_g)[g]$, where $[g]=\sum_{\exists a, h=a^{-1}ga}{h}\in A[G]$, or $[g]$ is the sum of elements in $G$ in the same conjugacy class of $g$. Why does this definition work?

Comment: You can read about the trace map in Passman's "The algebraic structure of group rings", section 2: The Trace Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace you want is called the [Hattori-Stallings trace](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156264/trace-of-finitely-generated-projective-module). It is a trace on endomorphisms of finitely presented projective $R$-modules, $R$ an arbitrary ring, which takes values in $R/[R, R]$.

If $R$ is a group algebra $A[G]$ over a commutative ring $A$ then $R/[R, R]$ is free as an $A$-module on a basis which can be identified with the conjugacy classes of $G$.